# Getting an image using the Google Drive PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to retrieve an image located in a Google Drive using the PHP API.  Authorisation works, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the image file to place it in a folder.  I have not found any results online.

Currently using

`$driveService->files->get($fileId)`,

where $driveService is a Google_Service_Drive class.

Then I'm trying to use the webContentLink to use it to download the file, but webContentLink is being set to null.  The image is located in a folder with edit permissions given to a service account, which is being used to access the images.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]  webContentLink is only available for binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webContentLink is only available for binary files.  If you are using file.get you can just write the get the body and write it out to the file.

```
$file = $service->files->get($fileId, array('alt' => 'media'));
file_put_contents("hello.pdf",$file->getBody());
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: my bad, it was an error with Intelliphense, thank you!